# How to edit the length of a FLAC file in Python?

Tags: python, mp3, google-cloud-platform, flac, google-speech-api

I am currently using Google's speech API and I a wondering is I can edit the length of the FLAC file that I am inputting into the program. e.g. I have a 7:30 length mp3 with 2 audio channels and I need it to be a 1 channel mono FLAC file with the length of 3 minutes for it to be input into the speech to text API.

Comment: You want to manually select the 3 minutes?  If that's the case, something like Audacity may be your best bet.

Comment: Thats what I have been using but I have so many audio files that I would like to automate this process. (over 300) @blambert

Comment: OK, so how would you choose the 3 minutes?  Or would you split the 7:30 min file into three files (3:00, 3:00, and 1:30)?  Why do you need them to be 3 minutes?

Comment: i need the first 3 minutes of every file. to be converted into a mono channel flac file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be done in Python as the headline says?  If its OK to do the conversion on a command line you could use a tool like `sox`.  For example:

```
sox audio.flac audio-short-mono.flac trim 0 180 remix 1,2
```

The `trim 0 180` option crops the audio to 180 seconds, and `remix 1,2` combines the two channels into one.